# Difference between int a[5],int a[], int a[]={2,3} in Java

Tags: java, arrays

How could we statically declare array? Can't it be by `int a[5];`?

```
package oops;

public class exception { 
    int arr1[] = new int[10];

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int a[] ={1,9};
        int[] a ;
        int a[9];
        a[0]=10;
    }
}
```

Comment: "`int a[9];`" is illegal because the size isn't part of the type.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following scenarios

```
// Create new array with the following two values
int a[] = {1,9};
Assert.assertTrue( 2 == a.length );
Assert.assertTrue( 1 == a[0] );
Assert.assertTrue( 9 == a[1] );

// Create a new, uninitialized array
int[] a;
Assert.assertTrue( null == a );
Assert.assertTrue( 0 == a.length ); // NullPointerException

int a[9]; // this will not compile, should be
int a[] = new int[9];
Assert.assertTrue( 9 == a.length );
Assert.assertTrue( null == a[0] );

// Provided 'a' has not been previously defined
int a[];
a[0] = 10; // NullPointerExcpetion

// Provided 'a' has been defined as having 0 indicies
int a[] = new int[0];
a[0] = 10; // IndexOutOfBoundsException

// Provided 'a' has been defined as an empty array
int a[] = new int[1];
a[0] = 10; // Reassign index 0, to value 10.
```

Comment: "Create a new, uninitialized array" Only if `int[] a` is a class variable. If it's a local variable, you'll get an error because it's not assigned.

Comment: "`null == a[0]`" won't compile, as `a[0]` is an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

`int a[] = {1,9}` is an array of two elements 1 and 9
`int[] a` is declaring an integer array called a.  Not initialized. `int a[9]` is an array containing nine elements.  Not initialized
`int[0]=10` places the value 10 in position 0 on the array

Comment: `int a[9];` is illegal

Comment: correct and was removed.

Answer (score 0):

`int arr1[] = new int[10];` - > an empty array of size 10 (memory allocated for it)

`int a[] ={1,9};` -> [1, 9] (creates an array with the values of 1 and 9)

`int[] a ;`       -> array that has been declared but not initialized

`int a[9];` -> doesn't work

See [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)